# How do I fix this regular expression?

Tags: java

```
(W[AY]|C[AO])(\\s+\\d{5})
```

So this currently parses states beginning with W or C followed by zip code. However, it returns all of them as one group as in 
Example WA 98121 CA 56679 will return Group 1 is WA 98121 and Group 2 is CA 56679.

How do I fix this to retrieve in group1 WA group2 98121 group3 CA group4 56679

Comment: What method are you using to execute the regex?

Comment: Each matcher should match a single state-zip combo. Try looking at group(1), group(2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you want to capture all parts of a search "phrase" in a single match, and break up the parts of the phrase by using groups, deal with the match then match again for the next phrase. So, I'm going to sidestep your question by showing you how to code using this approach.

Here's some runnable code that demonstrates how to match and use groups properly:

```
// Regex to match a "state zip" sequence, and capture each part in its own group
String regex = "(W[AY]|C[AO])\\s+(\\d{5})";

// Some sample input
String input = "blah blah WA 98121 blah blah CA 56679 blah blah";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).getMatcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) { // move to next match, if one exists
    String state = matcher.group(1);
    String zip = matcher.group(2);
    // Work with state and zip values
    System.out.println("State = " + state + ", zip = " + zip);
}
```

Output:

```
State = WA, zip = 98121
State = CA, zip = 56679
```

Note that captured regex groups are numbered from `1`.
FYI, group `0` is the entire match.